# Unable to input 2 separate .js scripts [Fixed]

Tags: javascript, html

'clock.js' is supposed to put a real-time clock in the top right corner of the webpage, and 'sparkles.js' puts sparkles under your cursor every time it moves.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="/clock.js"></script>

         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.ico"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    
      <script src="/sparkles.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

However I can only get one to work, I could put the whole code in for both (or just one) and it prioritizes only one of them. I could have them as far or close together as I want but it still doesn't work. It doesn't matter if I compress the javascript within the js file or not. I've looked everywhere for answers and have seen nothing.

```js
// <![CDATA[
var colour="#000000";
var clock_size=8;

var clok;
var cpos=0;
var newx=xmo=100;
var newy=ymo=30;
window.onload=function() { if (document.getElementById) {
  clok=document.createElement("div");
  clok.style.position="absolute";
  clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig0"));
  clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig1"));
  clok.appendChild(createColon());
  clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig2"));
  clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig3"));
  clok.appendChild(createColon("ms"));
  clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig4"));
  clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig5"));
  document.body.appendChild(clok);
  tick();
}}

var digit=new Array(247, 146, 221, 219, 186, 235, 239, 210, 255, 251);

function tick() {
  var now=new Date();
  var t=Math.floor(now.getTime()/500)%2;
  var i, j, k;
  var won=oo(now.getHours())+oo(now.getMinutes())+oo(now.getSeconds());
  for (i=0; i<6; i++) for (j=0; j<7; j++) {
    k=digit[won.substring(i, i+1)].toString(2).substring(j+1, j+2);
    document.getElementById("dig"+i+j).style.backgroundColor=(k==1)?colour:"transparent";
  }
  document.getElementById("mstop").style.backgroundColor=(t)?"transparent":colour;
  document.getElementById("msbot").style.backgroundColor=(t)?"transparent":colour;
  xmo+=Math.floor((newx-xmo)/4);
  clok.style.left=Math.round(xmo-(clock_size+2)*4)+"px";
  ymo+=Math.floor((newy-ymo)/4);
  clok.style.top=Math.round(ymo-clock_size*2.5)+"px";
  setTimeout("tick()", 40);
}


function scro() {
  var scro=0;
  if (document.body.scrollTop) scro=document.body.scrollTop;
  else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) scro=document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  return (scro);
}

function oo(o) { return(((o<10)?"0"+o:o).toString()); }

function createDigit(id) {
  var odiv=createDiv(0, cpos, clock_size+clock_size+2, clock_size+2, false);
  cpos+=clock_size+4;
  odiv.appendChild(createDiv(0, 1, 2, clock_size, id+"0"));
  odiv.appendChild(createDiv(1, 0, clock_size, 2, id+"1"));
  odiv.appendChild(createDiv(1, clock_size, clock_size, 2, id+"2"));
  odiv.appendChild(createDiv(clock_size, 1, 2, clock_size, id+"3"));
  odiv.appendChild(createDiv(clock_size+1, 0, clock_size, 2, id+"4"));
  odiv.appendChild(createDiv(clock_size+1, clock_size, clock_size, 2, id+"5"));
  odiv.appendChild(createDiv(clock_size+clock_size, 1, 2, clock_size, id+"6"));
  return (odiv);
}

function createColon(id) {
  var odiv=createDiv(0, cpos, clock_size+clock_size+2, 2, false);
  cpos+=4;
  var dot1=createDiv(4, 0, 3, 2, (id)?id+"top":false);
  dot1.style.backgroundColor=colour;
  odiv.appendChild(dot1);
  var dot2=createDiv(clock_size+clock_size-5, 0, 3, 2, (id)?id+"bot":false);
  dot2.style.backgroundColor=colour;
  odiv.appendChild(dot2);
  return (odiv);
}

function createDiv(top, left, height, width, id) {
  var div=document.createElement("div");
  div.style.position="absolute";
  div.style.top=top+"px";
  div.style.left=left+"px";
  div.style.height=height+"px";
  div.style.width=width+"px";
  div.style.overflow="hidden";
  if (id) div.setAttribute("id", id);
  return (div);
}
// ]]>

// <![CDATA[
var colour="#FFFFFF";
var sparkles=120;

var x=ox=400;
var y=oy=300;
var swide=800;
var shigh=600;
var sleft=sdown=0;
var tiny=new Array();
var star=new Array();
var starv=new Array();
var starx=new Array();
var stary=new Array();
var tinyx=new Array();
var tinyy=new Array();
var tinyv=new Array();

window.onload=function() { if (document.getElementById) {
  var i, rats, rlef, rdow;
  for (var i=0; i<sparkles; i++) {
    var rats=createDiv(3, 3);
    rats.style.visibility="hidden";
    document.body.appendChild(tiny[i]=rats);
    starv[i]=0;
    tinyv[i]=0;
    var rats=createDiv(5, 5);
    rats.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
    rats.style.visibility="hidden";
    var rlef=createDiv(1, 5);
    var rdow=createDiv(5, 1);
    rats.appendChild(rlef);
    rats.appendChild(rdow);
    rlef.style.top="2px";
    rlef.style.left="0px";
    rdow.style.top="0px";
    rdow.style.left="2px";
    document.body.appendChild(star[i]=rats);
  }
  set_width();
  sparkle();
}}

function sparkle() {
  var c;
  if (x!=ox || y!=oy) {
    ox=x;
    oy=y;
    for (c=0; c<sparkles; c++) if (!starv[c]) {
      star[c].style.left=(starx[c]=x)+"px";
      star[c].style.top=(stary[c]=y)+"px";
      star[c].style.clip="rect(0px, 5px, 5px, 0px)";
      star[c].style.visibility="visible";
      starv[c]=50;
      break;
    }
  }
  for (c=0; c<sparkles; c++) {
    if (starv[c]) update_star(c);
    if (tinyv[c]) update_tiny(c);
  }
  setTimeout("sparkle()", 40);
}

function update_star(i) {
  if (--starv[i]==25) star[i].style.clip="rect(1px, 4px, 4px, 1px)";
  if (starv[i]) {
    stary[i]+=1+Math.random()*3;
    if (stary[i]<shigh+sdown) {
      star[i].style.top=stary[i]+"px";
      starx[i]+=(i%5-2)/5;
      star[i].style.left=starx[i]+"px";
    }
    else {
      star[i].style.visibility="hidden";
      starv[i]=0;
      return;
    }
  }
  else {
    tinyv[i]=50;
    tiny[i].style.top=(tinyy[i]=stary[i])+"px";
    tiny[i].style.left=(tinyx[i]=starx[i])+"px";
    tiny[i].style.width="2px";
    tiny[i].style.height="2px";
    star[i].style.visibility="hidden";
    tiny[i].style.visibility="visible"
  }
}

function update_tiny(i) {
  if (--tinyv[i]==25) {
    tiny[i].style.width="1px";
    tiny[i].style.height="1px";
  }
  if (tinyv[i]) {
    tinyy[i]+=1+Math.random()*3;
    if (tinyy[i]<shigh+sdown) {
      tiny[i].style.top=tinyy[i]+"px";
      tinyx[i]+=(i%5-2)/5;
      tiny[i].style.left=tinyx[i]+"px";
    }
    else {
      tiny[i].style.visibility="hidden";
      tinyv[i]=0;
      return;
    }
  }
  else tiny[i].style.visibility="hidden";
}

document.onmousemove=mouse;
function mouse(e) {
  set_scroll();
  y=(e)?e.pageY:event.y+sdown;
  x=(e)?e.pageX:event.x+sleft;
}

function set_scroll() {
  if (typeof(self.pageYOffset)=="number") {
    sdown=self.pageYOffset;
    sleft=self.pageXOffset;
  }
  else if (document.body.scrollTop || document.body.scrollLeft) {
    sdown=document.body.scrollTop;
    sleft=document.body.scrollLeft;
  }
  else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollLeft)) {
    sleft=document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    sdown=document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
  else {
    sdown=0;
    sleft=0;
  }
}

window.onresize=set_width;
function set_width() {
  if (typeof(self.innerWidth)=="number") {
    swide=self.innerWidth;
    shigh=self.innerHeight;
  }
  else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
    swide=document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    shigh=document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  }
  else if (document.body.clientWidth) {
    swide=document.body.clientWidth;
    shigh=document.body.clientHeight;
  }
}

function createDiv(height, width) {
  var div=document.createElement("div");
  div.style.position="absolute";
  div.style.height=height+"px";
  div.style.width=width+"px";
  div.style.overflow="hidden";
  div.style.backgroundColor=colour;
  return (div);
}
// ]]>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="/clock.js"></script>

         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.ico"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    
      <script src="/sparkles.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet about the problem?

Comment: Have you tried putting the whole code in 1 file, just as a test if that is working?

Comment: It feels to me thet the clock only attaches to the page once and updatesd that, while sparkles would only attach things after the page is ready. Try moving both scripts to the end of your `<body>` tag. Also, if a script is not working there should be errors in the console, so have a look at that.

Comment: maybe the scripts overrides something. for example both have a line like `document.something = fun` so the previous one gets ignored but we don't have the scripts so can't tell anything

Comment: @LajosArpad Eleborate please?

Comment: @Geilmaker I have, unfortunately when I do so everything within the file only attaches to the clock.

Comment: @somethinghere I just did and neither of the scripts worked. I'm unsure of what you mean by console, but if it matters i'm using this script on Neocities. I have seen others do what i've been trying to (with success!) so I have no idea why i'm having this issue.

Comment: @VagifVALIYEV I haven't really checked the files past what i've modified, but the sparkles is from here: https://www.mf2fm.com/rv/dhtmltinkerbell.php
and the clock is from here: https://www.mf2fm.com/rv/dhtmldigitalwatch.php

I've modified the clock slightly so it doesn't follow the cursor and i've had no issues with either of these on their own.

Comment: What do you mean _unsure what I mean with console_? Open your web console (easiest way is Right Click, Inspect Element, then select "console") and see if there are any errors marked in red in your included JS. This should be step 1.

Comment: @somethinghere No need to be rude, I didn't know that. I just checked and it hasn't detected any issues.

Comment: @Das I mean that you can edit your question, you have a button in the editor that says "Create snippet" when you hover it and then you can add your HTML, CSS and Javascript in order to create a reproducible minimal example of the problem. That would largely help us seeing what your exact problem is.

Comment: @LajosArpad Snippet added (took me a bit, apologies). However I had to put the js files together, which is something i've already tried with no success.

I've also tried a different code from the same site I got the clock and sparkles from, and that worked with the clock, but the sparkles and the clock don't work together still.

Comment: @Das excellent. I see you already have an accepted answer, I'm glad the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I solved it. Just use the sparkles script first and clock script next. And also instead of loading the both clock and sparkles functions at the same time, I changed the loading time of the clock function to 100 miliseconds after the pageload. And after that it works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
  <!-- sparkles script -->
  <script>
    var colour="random"; // "random" can be replaced with any valid colour ie: "red"...
    var sparkles=100;// increase of decrease for number of sparkles falling

    var x=ox=400;
    var y=oy=300;
    var swide=800;
    var shigh=600;
    var sleft=sdown=0;
    var tiny=new Array();
    var star=new Array();
    var starv=new Array();
    var starx=new Array();
    var stary=new Array();
    var tinyx=new Array();
    var tinyy=new Array();
    var tinyv=new Array();

    colours=new Array('#ff0000','#00ff00','#ffffff','#ff00ff','#ffa500','#ffff00','#00ff00','#ffffff','ff00ff')

    n = 10;
    y = 0;
    x = 0;
    n6=(document.getElementById&&!document.all);
    ns=(document.layers);
    ie=(document.all);
    d=(ns||ie)?'document.':'document.getElementById("';
    a=(ns||n6)?'':'all.';
    n6r=(n6)?'")':'';
    s=(ns)?'':'.style';

    if (ns){
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        document.write('<layer name="dots'+i+'" top=0 left=0 width='+i/2+' height='+i/2+' bgcolor=#ff0000></layer>');
    }

    if (ie)
      document.write('<div id="con" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px"><div style="position:relative">');

    if (ie||n6){
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        document.write('<div id="dots'+i+'" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:'+i/2+'px;height:'+i/2+'px;background:#ff0000;font-size:'+i/2+'"></div>');
    }

    if (ie)
      document.write('</div></div>');
    (ns||n6)?window.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE):0;

    function Mouse(evnt){

      y = (ns||n6)?evnt.pageY+4 - window.pageYOffset:event.y+4;
      x = (ns||n6)?evnt.pageX+1:event.x+1;
    }

    (ns)?window.onMouseMove=Mouse:document.onmousemove=Mouse;

    function animate(){

      o=(ns||n6)?window.pageYOffset:0;

      if (ie)con.style.top=document.body.scrollTop + 'px';

      for (i = 0; i < n; i++){

        var temp1 = eval(d+a+"dots"+i+n6r+s);

        randcolours = colours[Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length)];

        (ns)?temp1.bgColor = randcolours:temp1.background = randcolours; 

        if (i < n-1){

          var temp2 = eval(d+a+"dots"+(i+1)+n6r+s);
          temp1.top = parseInt(temp2.top) + 'px';
          temp1.left = parseInt(temp2.left) + 'px';

        } 
        else{

          temp1.top = y+o + 'px';
          temp1.left = x + 'px';
        }
      }

      setTimeout("animate()",10);
    }

    animate();

    window.onload=function() { if (document.getElementById) {
      var i, rats, rlef, rdow;
      for (var i=0; i<sparkles; i++) {
        var rats=createDiv(3, 3);
        rats.style.visibility="hidden";
        rats.style.zIndex="999";
        document.body.appendChild(tiny[i]=rats);
        starv[i]=0;
        tinyv[i]=0;
        var rats=createDiv(5, 5);
        rats.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
        rats.style.visibility="hidden";
        rats.style.zIndex="999";
        var rlef=createDiv(1, 5);
        var rdow=createDiv(5, 1);
        rats.appendChild(rlef);
        rats.appendChild(rdow);
        rlef.style.top="2px";
        rlef.style.left="0px";
        rdow.style.top="0px";
        rdow.style.left="2px";
        document.body.appendChild(star[i]=rats);
      }
      set_width();
      sparkle();
    }}

    function sparkle() {
      var c;
      if (Math.abs(x-ox)>1 || Math.abs(y-oy)>1) {
        ox=x;
        oy=y;
        for (c=0; c<sparkles; c++) if (!starv[c]) {
          star[c].style.left=(starx[c]=x)+"px";
          star[c].style.top=(stary[c]=y+1)+"px";
          star[c].style.clip="rect(0px, 5px, 5px, 0px)";
          star[c].childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor=star[c].childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor=(colour=="random")?newColour():colour;
          star[c].style.visibility="visible";
          starv[c]=50;
          break;
        }
      }
      for (c=0; c<sparkles; c++) {
        if (starv[c]) update_star(c);
        if (tinyv[c]) update_tiny(c);
      }
      setTimeout("sparkle()", 40);
    }

    function update_star(i) {
      if (--starv[i]==25) star[i].style.clip="rect(1px, 4px, 4px, 1px)";
      if (starv[i]) {
        stary[i]+=1+Math.random()*3;
        starx[i]+=(i%5-2)/5;
        if (stary[i]<shigh+sdown) {
          star[i].style.top=stary[i]+"px";
          star[i].style.left=starx[i]+"px";
        }
        else {
          star[i].style.visibility="hidden";
          starv[i]=0;
          return;
        }
      }
      else {
        tinyv[i]=50;
        tiny[i].style.top=(tinyy[i]=stary[i])+"px";
        tiny[i].style.left=(tinyx[i]=starx[i])+"px";
        tiny[i].style.width="2px";
        tiny[i].style.height="2px";
        tiny[i].style.backgroundColor=star[i].childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor;
        star[i].style.visibility="hidden";
        tiny[i].style.visibility="visible"
      }
    }

    function update_tiny(i) {
      if (--tinyv[i]==25) {
        tiny[i].style.width="1px";
        tiny[i].style.height="1px";
      }
      if (tinyv[i]) {
        tinyy[i]+=1+Math.random()*3;
        tinyx[i]+=(i%5-2)/5;
        if (tinyy[i]<shigh+sdown) {
          tiny[i].style.top=tinyy[i]+"px";
          tiny[i].style.left=tinyx[i]+"px";
        }
        else {
          tiny[i].style.visibility="hidden";
          tinyv[i]=0;
          return;
        }
      }
      else tiny[i].style.visibility="hidden";
    }

    document.onmousemove=mouse;
    function mouse(e) {
      if (e) {
        y=e.pageY;
        x=e.pageX;
      }
      else {
        set_scroll();
        y=event.y+sdown;
        x=event.x+sleft;
      }
    }

    window.onscroll=set_scroll;
    function set_scroll() {
      if (typeof(self.pageYOffset)=='number') {
        sdown=self.pageYOffset;
        sleft=self.pageXOffset;
      }
      else if (document.body && (document.body.scrollTop || document.body.scrollLeft)) {
        sdown=document.body.scrollTop;
        sleft=document.body.scrollLeft;
      }
      else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollLeft)) {
        sleft=document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        sdown=document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      }
      else {
        sdown=0;
        sleft=0;
      }
    }

    window.onresize=set_width;
    function set_width() {
      var sw_min=999999;
      var sh_min=999999;
      if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
        if (document.documentElement.clientWidth>0) sw_min=document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        if (document.documentElement.clientHeight>0) sh_min=document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      }
      if (typeof(self.innerWidth)=='number' && self.innerWidth) {
        if (self.innerWidth>0 && self.innerWidth<sw_min) sw_min=self.innerWidth;
        if (self.innerHeight>0 && self.innerHeight<sh_min) sh_min=self.innerHeight;
      }
      if (document.body.clientWidth) {
        if (document.body.clientWidth>0 && document.body.clientWidth<sw_min) sw_min=document.body.clientWidth;
        if (document.body.clientHeight>0 && document.body.clientHeight<sh_min) sh_min=document.body.clientHeight;
      }
      if (sw_min==999999 || sh_min==999999) {
        sw_min=800;
        sh_min=600;
      }
      swide=sw_min;
      shigh=sh_min;
    }

    function createDiv(height, width) {
      var div=document.createElement("div");
      div.style.position="absolute";
      div.style.height=height+"px";
      div.style.width=width+"px";
      div.style.overflow="hidden";
      return (div);
    }

    function newColour() {
      var c=new Array();
      c[0]=255;
      c[1]=Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
      c[2]=Math.floor(Math.random()*(256-c[1]/2));
      c.sort(function(){return (0.5 - Math.random());});
      return ("rgb("+c[0]+", "+c[1]+", "+c[2]+")");
    }
  </script>
  </div>
  
  <!-- clock script -->
  <div>
  <script>    
    var colour="#000000";
    var clock_size=8;

    var clok;
    var cpos=0;
    var newx=xmo=100;
    var newy=ymo=30;
    setTimeout(function() { if (document.getElementById) {
      clok=document.createElement("div");
      clok.style.position="absolute";
      clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig0"));
      clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig1"));
      clok.appendChild(createColon());
      clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig2"));
      clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig3"));
      clok.appendChild(createColon("ms"));
      clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig4"));
      clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig5"));
      document.body.appendChild(clok);
      tick();
    }},100);

    var digit=new Array(247, 146, 221, 219, 186, 235, 239, 210, 255, 251);

    function tick() {
      var now=new Date();
      var t=Math.floor(now.getTime()/500)%2;
      var i, j, k;
      var won=oo(now.getHours())+oo(now.getMinutes())+oo(now.getSeconds());
      for (i=0; i<6; i++) for (j=0; j<7; j++) {
        k=digit[won.substring(i, i+1)].toString(2).substring(j+1, j+2);
        document.getElementById("dig"+i+j).style.backgroundColor=(k==1)?colour:"transparent";
      }
      document.getElementById("mstop").style.backgroundColor=(t)?"transparent":colour;
      document.getElementById("msbot").style.backgroundColor=(t)?"transparent":colour;
      xmo+=Math.floor((newx-xmo)/4);
      clok.style.left=Math.round(xmo-(clock_size+2)*4)+"px";
      ymo+=Math.floor((newy-ymo)/4);
      clok.style.top=Math.round(ymo-clock_size*2.5)+"px";
      setTimeout("tick()", 40);
    }


    function scro() {
      var scro=0;
      if (document.body.scrollTop) scro=document.body.scrollTop;
      else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) scro=document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      return (scro);
    }

    function oo(o) { return(((o<10)?"0"+o:o).toString()); }

    function createDigit(id) {
      var odiv=createDiv(0, cpos, clock_size+clock_size+2, clock_size+2, false);
      cpos+=clock_size+4;
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(0, 1, 2, clock_size, id+"0"));
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(1, 0, clock_size, 2, id+"1"));
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(1, clock_size, clock_size, 2, id+"2"));
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(clock_size, 1, 2, clock_size, id+"3"));
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(clock_size+1, 0, clock_size, 2, id+"4"));
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(clock_size+1, clock_size, clock_size, 2, id+"5"));
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(clock_size+clock_size, 1, 2, clock_size, id+"6"));
      return (odiv);
    }

    function createColon(id) {
      var odiv=createDiv(0, cpos, clock_size+clock_size+2, 2, false);
      cpos+=4;
      var dot1=createDiv(4, 0, 3, 2, (id)?id+"top":false);
      dot1.style.backgroundColor=colour;
      odiv.appendChild(dot1);
      var dot2=createDiv(clock_size+clock_size-5, 0, 3, 2, (id)?id+"bot":false);
      dot2.style.backgroundColor=colour;
      odiv.appendChild(dot2);
      return (odiv);
    }

    function createDiv(top, left, height, width, id) {
      var div=document.createElement("div");
      div.style.position="absolute";
      div.style.top=top+"px";
      div.style.left=left+"px";
      div.style.height=height+"px";
      div.style.width=width+"px";
      div.style.overflow="hidden";
      if (id) div.setAttribute("id", id);
      return (div);
    }
  </script>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

In this version, there will not be any tiny sparkles. For this one, you don't need to make any difference between those 2 functions run time. Simply put the sparkles script first and clock script next and it will work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
  <!-- sparkes script -->
  <script>
    var colour="random"; // "random" can be replaced with any valid colour ie: "red"...
    var sparkles=100;// increase of decrease for number of sparkles falling

    var x=ox=400;
    var y=oy=300;
    var swide=800;
    var shigh=600;
    var sleft=sdown=0;
    var tiny=new Array();
    var star=new Array();
    var starv=new Array();
    var starx=new Array();
    var stary=new Array();
    var tinyx=new Array();
    var tinyy=new Array();
    var tinyv=new Array();

    colours=new Array('#ff0000','#00ff00','#ffffff','#ff00ff','#ffa500','#ffff00','#00ff00','#ffffff','ff00ff')

    n = 10;
    y = 0;
    x = 0;
    n6=(document.getElementById&&!document.all);
    ns=(document.layers);
    ie=(document.all);
    d=(ns||ie)?'document.':'document.getElementById("';
    a=(ns||n6)?'':'all.';
    n6r=(n6)?'")':'';
    s=(ns)?'':'.style';

    if (ns){
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        document.write('<layer name="dots'+i+'" top=0 left=0 width='+i/2+' height='+i/2+' bgcolor=#ff0000></layer>');
    }

    if (ie)
      document.write('<div id="con" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px"><div style="position:relative">');

    if (ie||n6){
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        document.write('<div id="dots'+i+'" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:'+i/2+'px;height:'+i/2+'px;background:#ff0000;font-size:'+i/2+'"></div>');
    }

    if (ie)
      document.write('</div></div>');
    (ns||n6)?window.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE):0;

    function Mouse(evnt){

      y = (ns||n6)?evnt.pageY+4 - window.pageYOffset:event.y+4;
      x = (ns||n6)?evnt.pageX+1:event.x+1;
    }

    (ns)?window.onMouseMove=Mouse:document.onmousemove=Mouse;

    function animate(){

      o=(ns||n6)?window.pageYOffset:0;

      if (ie)con.style.top=document.body.scrollTop + 'px';

      for (i = 0; i < n; i++){

        var temp1 = eval(d+a+"dots"+i+n6r+s);

        randcolours = colours[Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length)];

        (ns)?temp1.bgColor = randcolours:temp1.background = randcolours; 

        if (i < n-1){

          var temp2 = eval(d+a+"dots"+(i+1)+n6r+s);
          temp1.top = parseInt(temp2.top) + 'px';
          temp1.left = parseInt(temp2.left) + 'px';

        } 
        else{

          temp1.top = y+o + 'px';
          temp1.left = x + 'px';
        }
      }

      setTimeout("animate()",10);
    }

    animate();

    window.onload=function() { if (document.getElementById) {
      var i, rats, rlef, rdow;
      for (var i=0; i<sparkles; i++) {
        var rats=createDiv(3, 3);
        rats.style.visibility="hidden";
        rats.style.zIndex="999";
        document.body.appendChild(tiny[i]=rats);
        starv[i]=0;
        tinyv[i]=0;
        var rats=createDiv(5, 5);
        rats.style.backgroundColor="transparent";
        rats.style.visibility="hidden";
        rats.style.zIndex="999";
        var rlef=createDiv(1, 5);
        var rdow=createDiv(5, 1);
        rats.appendChild(rlef);
        rats.appendChild(rdow);
        rlef.style.top="2px";
        rlef.style.left="0px";
        rdow.style.top="0px";
        rdow.style.left="2px";
        document.body.appendChild(star[i]=rats);
      }
      set_width();
      sparkle();
    }}

    function sparkle() {
      var c;
      if (Math.abs(x-ox)>1 || Math.abs(y-oy)>1) {
        ox=x;
        oy=y;
        for (c=0; c<sparkles; c++) if (!starv[c]) {
          star[c].style.left=(starx[c]=x)+"px";
          star[c].style.top=(stary[c]=y+1)+"px";
          star[c].style.clip="rect(0px, 5px, 5px, 0px)";
          star[c].childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor=star[c].childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor=(colour=="random")?newColour():colour;
          star[c].style.visibility="visible";
          starv[c]=50;
          break;
        }
      }
      for (c=0; c<sparkles; c++) {
        if (starv[c]) update_star(c);
        if (tinyv[c]) update_tiny(c);
      }
      setTimeout("sparkle()", 40);
    }

    function update_star(i) {
      if (--starv[i]==25) star[i].style.clip="rect(1px, 4px, 4px, 1px)";
      if (starv[i]) {
        stary[i]+=1+Math.random()*3;
        starx[i]+=(i%5-2)/5;
        if (stary[i]<shigh+sdown) {
          star[i].style.top=stary[i]+"px";
          star[i].style.left=starx[i]+"px";
        }
        else {
          star[i].style.visibility="hidden";
          starv[i]=0;
          return;
        }
      }
      else {
        tinyv[i]=50;
        tiny[i].style.top=(tinyy[i]=stary[i])+"px";
        tiny[i].style.left=(tinyx[i]=starx[i])+"px";
        tiny[i].style.width="2px";
        tiny[i].style.height="2px";
        tiny[i].style.backgroundColor=star[i].childNodes[0].style.backgroundColor;
        star[i].style.visibility="hidden";
        tiny[i].style.visibility="visible"
      }
    }

    function update_tiny(i) {
      if (--tinyv[i]==25) {
        tiny[i].style.width="1px";
        tiny[i].style.height="1px";
      }
      if (tinyv[i]) {
        tinyy[i]+=1+Math.random()*3;
        tinyx[i]+=(i%5-2)/5;
        if (tinyy[i]<shigh+sdown) {
          tiny[i].style.top=tinyy[i]+"px";
          tiny[i].style.left=tinyx[i]+"px";
        }
        else {
          tiny[i].style.visibility="hidden";
          tinyv[i]=0;
          return;
        }
      }
      else tiny[i].style.visibility="hidden";
    }

    document.onmousemove=mouse;
    function mouse(e) {
      if (e) {
        y=e.pageY;
        x=e.pageX;
      }
      else {
        set_scroll();
        y=event.y+sdown;
        x=event.x+sleft;
      }
    }

    window.onscroll=set_scroll;
    function set_scroll() {
      if (typeof(self.pageYOffset)=='number') {
        sdown=self.pageYOffset;
        sleft=self.pageXOffset;
      }
      else if (document.body && (document.body.scrollTop || document.body.scrollLeft)) {
        sdown=document.body.scrollTop;
        sleft=document.body.scrollLeft;
      }
      else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollLeft)) {
        sleft=document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        sdown=document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      }
      else {
        sdown=0;
        sleft=0;
      }
    }

    window.onresize=set_width;
    function set_width() {
      var sw_min=999999;
      var sh_min=999999;
      if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
        if (document.documentElement.clientWidth>0) sw_min=document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        if (document.documentElement.clientHeight>0) sh_min=document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      }
      if (typeof(self.innerWidth)=='number' && self.innerWidth) {
        if (self.innerWidth>0 && self.innerWidth<sw_min) sw_min=self.innerWidth;
        if (self.innerHeight>0 && self.innerHeight<sh_min) sh_min=self.innerHeight;
      }
      if (document.body.clientWidth) {
        if (document.body.clientWidth>0 && document.body.clientWidth<sw_min) sw_min=document.body.clientWidth;
        if (document.body.clientHeight>0 && document.body.clientHeight<sh_min) sh_min=document.body.clientHeight;
      }
      if (sw_min==999999 || sh_min==999999) {
        sw_min=800;
        sh_min=600;
      }
      swide=sw_min;
      shigh=sh_min;
    }

    function createDiv(height, width) {
      var div=document.createElement("div");
      div.style.position="absolute";
      div.style.height=height+"px";
      div.style.width=width+"px";
      div.style.overflow="hidden";
      return (div);
    }

    function newColour() {
      var c=new Array();
      c[0]=255;
      c[1]=Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
      c[2]=Math.floor(Math.random()*(256-c[1]/2));
      c.sort(function(){return (0.5 - Math.random());});
      return ("rgb("+c[0]+", "+c[1]+", "+c[2]+")");
    }
  </script>
  </div>
  
  <!-- clock script -->
  <div>
  <script>    
    var colour="#000000";
    var clock_size=8;

    var clok;
    var cpos=0;
    var newx=xmo=100;
    var newy=ymo=30;
    window.onload=function() { if (document.getElementById) {
      clok=document.createElement("div");
      clok.style.position="absolute";
      clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig0"));
      clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig1"));
      clok.appendChild(createColon());
      clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig2"));
      clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig3"));
      clok.appendChild(createColon("ms"));
      clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig4"));
      clok.appendChild(createDigit("dig5"));
      document.body.appendChild(clok);
      tick();
    }}

    var digit=new Array(247, 146, 221, 219, 186, 235, 239, 210, 255, 251);

    function tick() {
      var now=new Date();
      var t=Math.floor(now.getTime()/500)%2;
      var i, j, k;
      var won=oo(now.getHours())+oo(now.getMinutes())+oo(now.getSeconds());
      for (i=0; i<6; i++) for (j=0; j<7; j++) {
        k=digit[won.substring(i, i+1)].toString(2).substring(j+1, j+2);
        document.getElementById("dig"+i+j).style.backgroundColor=(k==1)?colour:"transparent";
      }
      document.getElementById("mstop").style.backgroundColor=(t)?"transparent":colour;
      document.getElementById("msbot").style.backgroundColor=(t)?"transparent":colour;
      xmo+=Math.floor((newx-xmo)/4);
      clok.style.left=Math.round(xmo-(clock_size+2)*4)+"px";
      ymo+=Math.floor((newy-ymo)/4);
      clok.style.top=Math.round(ymo-clock_size*2.5)+"px";
      setTimeout("tick()", 40);
    }


    function scro() {
      var scro=0;
      if (document.body.scrollTop) scro=document.body.scrollTop;
      else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) scro=document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      return (scro);
    }

    function oo(o) { return(((o<10)?"0"+o:o).toString()); }

    function createDigit(id) {
      var odiv=createDiv(0, cpos, clock_size+clock_size+2, clock_size+2, false);
      cpos+=clock_size+4;
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(0, 1, 2, clock_size, id+"0"));
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(1, 0, clock_size, 2, id+"1"));
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(1, clock_size, clock_size, 2, id+"2"));
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(clock_size, 1, 2, clock_size, id+"3"));
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(clock_size+1, 0, clock_size, 2, id+"4"));
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(clock_size+1, clock_size, clock_size, 2, id+"5"));
      odiv.appendChild(createDiv(clock_size+clock_size, 1, 2, clock_size, id+"6"));
      return (odiv);
    }

    function createColon(id) {
      var odiv=createDiv(0, cpos, clock_size+clock_size+2, 2, false);
      cpos+=4;
      var dot1=createDiv(4, 0, 3, 2, (id)?id+"top":false);
      dot1.style.backgroundColor=colour;
      odiv.appendChild(dot1);
      var dot2=createDiv(clock_size+clock_size-5, 0, 3, 2, (id)?id+"bot":false);
      dot2.style.backgroundColor=colour;
      odiv.appendChild(dot2);
      return (odiv);
    }

    function createDiv(top, left, height, width, id) {
      var div=document.createElement("div");
      div.style.position="absolute";
      div.style.top=top+"px";
      div.style.left=left+"px";
      div.style.height=height+"px";
      div.style.width=width+"px";
      div.style.overflow="hidden";
      if (id) div.setAttribute("id", id);
      return (div);
    }
  </script>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That looks awesome to me! :)

Comment: This works perfectly! But one question: there are tiny sparkles that are a second behind the ones that follow the cursor, is it possible to remove those without messing with the larger ones?

Comment: Sure, it is simpler than the first one. I updated the answer with another version. Please check it.

Comment: If it helps feel free to upvote the answer as well.